# Can someone please explain this JavaScript regular expression for me?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please explain this JavaScript regular expression for me?

```
new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)"), ' ')
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier: "\\b" + className + "\\b" ?

Comment: @Manu - no.  It's tempting to do that, but dashes are valid characters in CSS class names.  And, for better or worse, dashes are surrounded by word boundaries.

Answer (score 11):

```
(             Either
  ^               the start of the string
|               or
  \\s+            one or more whitespace characters
)             followed by
className       the class name in question
(             followed by either
  \\s+          one or more whitespace characters
|             or
  $             the end of the string
)
```

So it will match "pog" in:

```
"pog"
"  pog"
"pog  "
"pog bim"
"bim pog"
"  pog bim"
"bim pog  "
"bim pog pam"
```

etc.

The second argument to `new RegExp()` can give options, eg. "i" meaning "case insensitive".  In your case you're not passing any options (which is correct if you're dealing with HTML class names - class names should be treated case-sensitively).

Comment: I believe this also traps whats inside the parenthesis for look backs, which wouldn't give you much regardless.

Comment: @Tom - correct.  You could modify the subpatterns with ?: to prevent match capturing, but it's not really needed in this case.

Answer (score 5):

RichieHindle has a great answer.  I just wanted to add some info about the purpose of this pattern.

When you're checking if an element has a given CSS class, you want to avoid false positives.  If your regexp was too simple, like this

```
var pattern = new RegExp( className );
```

Then an element with the class "fooBar" would test positive for a check on the class "foo".  These boundary subpatterns exists here to prevent this type of scenario.  Here's a demo of it in action

```
<div id="test1" class="red big">My class is "red big"</div>
<div id="test2" class="red-and-big green">My class is "red-and-big green"</div>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var ta = document.getElementById( 'output' );
    var test1 = document.getElementById( 'test1' );
    var test2 = document.getElementById( 'test2' );

    function hasCssClass( classList, className )
    {
        var pattern = new RegExp( "(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)" );
        return pattern.test( classList );
    }

    function testElement( elem, className )
    {
        var has = hasCssClass( elem.className, className )
        ta.value += elem.id + ' ' + ( has ? 'has' : 'does not have' ) + ' ' + className + "\n";
    }

    testElement( test1, 'red' );
    testElement( test1, 'green' );
    testElement( test1, 'big' );
    testElement( test1, 'red-and-big' );

    testElement( test2, 'red' );
    testElement( test2, 'big' );
    testElement( test2, 'green' );
    testElement( test2, 'red-and-big' );


</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's looking for classnames.

Match the start of a newline or whitespace `(^|\s)`, then the classname, then the classname can be followed by a space or the end of line `($|\s)`.

Answer (score 1):

It searches for the contents of `classname` in a whitespace-delimited list.  It seems that it was made to parse the className property of DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

Matches that class name if it's preceded by the beginning (^) or a space (`\\s`) in front of it, and it's followed by a space after it or the end ($).

Answer (score 0):

The first fragment matches either whitespace or the beginning of a string.  The last fragment similarly matches either whitespace or the end of a string.  This is done so that a check for a classname of "foo" doesn't match an element whose only classname is "foobar".

Answer (score 0):

w3schools has some great intro and try yourself tutorials for all sorts of development topics.
Check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp

And then for pattern matching look for a cheat sheet you like, 
I always ended up on http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

hope these sites help.